# write a very long list (and assign variable) to file without text wrapping problems

Tags: python, list, dump

I create a very long list of strings in python and want to write this to a JavaScript file without running into text wrapping issues.
In addition, if it is possible to do automatically in python, I would like to assign a variable to this list.  This should be done from python, but the variable should exist in the .js file.  I.e. adding code, not a string.

what I have:

```
lList_x = []
list_name = open('path/to/list.js', 'w+')

#list creation...
lList_x.append(stuff)

simplejson.dump(lList_x, list_name)

list_name.close()
```

This creates the list in list.js `["a","b","c","d",....]`

The problem here is that the lists that I am creating are between 10 000 and 500 000 characters long, so that the list is split up after every 1024 characters, which destroys the list.  This also renders the file list.js read-only in many text editors.
Thus, how do I create this list but add every element onto a new line?

I also want to assign a variable to the list automatically in python during the list creation.  Is this possible?

So what I want in my js file:

```
window.lX = ["a",
"b",
"c",
...]
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the documentation](http://simplejson.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#basic-usage), you can set `indent=""` to make `dump` "pretty print" across multiple lines without indentation:

```
simplejson.dump(lList_x, list_name, indent="")
```

From the docs:

> If `indent` is a string, then JSON array elements and object members will be pretty-printed with a newline followed by that string repeated for each level of nesting.

Comment: I was trying this with the `json` module since I don't have Python2.5 handy. It seems `indent` now needs to be an integer, so `indent=0` if you are using `json` instead of `simplejson`

Comment: @gnibbler that's interesting - the notes on `simplejson` suggest that it went from an integer *to* a string!

Comment: Perhaps that change was after simplejson was adopted by Python, so the json module has the older semantics?

Answer (score 1):

how about manually constructing the list:

```
list_name.write("window.lX = [\n")
for item in lList_x:
    print list_name.write(json.dumps(item), ",\n")
```